# Spring Batch Singleton Reader and Multi Threaded Processor

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have to configure a job using Spring Batch. Is it possible to have a single threaded ItemReader but But Multi Threaded processor?

In this case ItemReader will create the work-items to be processed by reading it from database (by executing predefined query) and each processor will process item/chunk in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `AsyncItemProcessor` and `AsyncItemWriter` from the spring-batch-integration module.  What those do is the `AsyncItemProcessor` is executed in a different thread, returning a `Future`.  The `AsyncItemWriter` then unwraps the `Future` and writes the result.  You can read more about this in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/integration/async/AsyncItemProcessor.html